# Constant current source to heat thermistor rapidly

Tags: constant-current, thermistor

My goal is to heat a thermistor as rapidly as possible.

The thermistor has a resistance value of 10k Ohms at 25 degrees C, and a negative temperature coefficient.

If I apply a constant voltage of 12V, the thermistor requires 30-50 seconds to heat up by 5-10 deg C above its starting temp. I would like the thermistor to reach 5-10 deg C above its start temp in less than 3 seconds, preferably within 1 second.

I am using a power source that can provide up to 30V, with a max draw of 3A.

I am considering using a constant-current source to try to achieve this goal, such as http://www.instructables.com/id/Constant-Current-Source-with-Operational-Amplifier/, but modified to provide greater current than the example project. Will this work toward my goal? Or are there better circuit options I could consider?

Comment: Have you calculated how much power is required to heat it in the required part and that your power supply is sufficient for this?

Comment: If 12V produces a heat-up time of 30-50 seconds, how likely is it that 30V (the top limit of your supply and only 2.5x 12V) is really going to reduce that by a factor of 30? Even if your unspecified thermistor is capable of surviving the amount of power dissipation necessary?

Comment: Eugene, thanks -- I'll need to determine the mass to figure that out, so let me get back to you. Good suggestion.

Comment: brhans, the current draw when heating is only 0.4mA (thermistor is in voltage divider with 20k resistor), so if I could add more current I could increase the power to the thermistor.

Comment: @ThermalModeler - Please pay as much attention to brhans as you are to Eugene. What thermistor are you using, how hot will it get if it dissipates the power you need, and can it survive that power level? And why are you using a thermistor as a heater? It will be unstable when driven by a voltage source (thermal runaway possible), and difficult to overdrive with a current source (rising temp lowers resistance, so power dissipation drops).

Comment: You can't just use a simple constant current source powered by the 30V supply, as it will be limited to 30V.  You'll need to convert the 30V to a higher voltage using a boost converter.  Can you calculate what voltage you need?

Comment: Ohm's law. I=V/R. Your 10k thermistor + 20k resistor = 30k. The most current you can therefore expect when your supply is at its 30V maximum is 30/30k = 1mA. Which as, as we expected, only 2.5x what you had before. 2.5x more current gives you 6.25x more power (with the same resistance).

Comment: Again, Why are you using a thermistor as a heater?  That is a device used for measuring temperatures.  Any old resistor could be a heater.

Comment: @RDrast Good point.

Comment: @ThermalModeler: You have not provided nearly enough information to allow this question to be answered. To start with, where's the datasheet for your thermistor? Also, in your application, are you restricted to strictly self-heating of the thermistor? What else is getting heated by the thermistor? What's the purpose of the 20K resistor? Remember, we're not mind-readers, and if you want good answers, you need to put some effort into asking a detailed and specific question.

Comment: There are legitimate reasons to use a self-heated thermistor.  Detecting airflow is one, the resistance will change dramatically due to the cooling from moving vs. still air.  Usually done with a hot wire, but a thermistor works as well.

Comment: @RDrast What JohnD said. Also, as T_therm increases its resistance drops (as NTC) so for static thermal conditions ultimately a stable state will be reached which is a function of Vin Rseries, thermal R of thermistor and NTC curve shape. This can be made to behave in ways different than aa std resistor when various parameters change. Can be a temperature regulator of sorts or air flow sensor or ... .

Comment: If you figure out how much energy is required to heat your thermistor, you can heat it up quickly by storing the energy in an inductor, or capacitor, then dumping it into the thermistor at time T=0.

Comment: Thanks mkieth. That's a great idea. Looks like 9000 details weren't needed after all to answer the question.